# Does Karet apply in cases of Safek

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, karet, elu-velu-pluralism

If there is question which is a Machloket Halacha, and one takes a position which is lenient on a Safek D’oraita of a Karet level sin (such as say a dispute whether something constitutes a Melacha on Shabbat) are they “exempt” from Karet even if Hashem believes they’re wrong on the halachic matter (because they have what rabbis to rely upon for their opinion).

To summarize, if there is a doubt regarding an action which would normally have  Karet liability, does one ever get Karet for taking the lenient practice?

Comment: Is it a safek or something they ruled on?

Comment: Lo bashamayim hi.